# A set $U$ is open $\iff$ $\forall x \in U$, $\exists$ some open set $U_x$ containing $x$ such that $U_x \subseteq U$

Tags: general-topology

I had the following exercise in my lecture notes.

> Let $(X, τ)$ be a topological space. Prove that a set $U$ is open
> $\iff$ $\forall x \in U$, there exists some open set $U_x$ containing
> $x$ such that $U_x \subseteq U$.

Its proof does not care yet for me. I wanted to understand what is the proposition saying. I think its goal is to let us tell if a subset $S$ of $X$ is an open set or no ($S \in \tau$ or $S \notin \tau$).
So I took $X = \{0, 1, 2\}$ and the topology $τ = \{\emptyset, \{0\}, \{0, 1, 2\}\}$.
I want to know if $S=\{1, 2\} $ could be in $\tau$ or not. The answer should be yes, $τ' = \{\emptyset, \{0\}, \{1, 2\}, \{0, 1, 2\}\}$ is a topology too. I wanted to check with the given proposition, so if I take $x=1$, then the only $U_x$ that satisfies the proposition is $U_x=S$, so I am admitting that $S$ is an open set, but that's what I want to show ! So there is clearly a problem in this way of understanding the proposition. Can someone explain it to me, maybe with the same example that I took since I am just starting topological spaces ?

Answer (score 1):

You have already specified a topology $\tau$, so why are you looking at $\tau'$? The question is whether $S=\{1,2\}\in \tau$, and the answer is no. So, $S\notin \tau$, i.e $S$ is not an open subset of $X$, with respect to the topology $\tau$. You can also see this using the proposition: by equivalently phrasing the proposition in the negative sense, we have:

> $S$ is not open if and only if there exists $x\in S$ such that for every $V\in\tau$ which contains $x$, we have that $V$ is NOT a subset of $S$.

In the case of $S=\{1,2\}$, we can also see this because the specific element $x=1\in S$ is such that for every $V\in\tau$ which contains $x=1$ (in our case $\{0,1,2\}$ is the only such set), we have that $\{0,1,2\}$ is NOT a subset of $S=\{1,2\}$.

Comment: The direction $\Longleftarrow$ of the proposition tells us if a subset is open or not. What is the point for us to use this proposition if we can just see if the subset is in our topology ? I understood the proposition as a quick way to tell us if we can make the topology finer, so it has a useful goal... Do you get what I mean ? Excuse me if I made it unclear

Comment: @John Usually, for larger sets, the topology will be infinite, so we can't list out all the elements of $\tau$ and "see" if our set $S$ belongs to $\tau$, so we need a proposition like this (which is usually simpler to verify) to decide whether or not a set belongs to $\tau$.

Comment: @John For some topologies, specifying $\tau$ completely is more difficult, and it's usually easier to specify some subset of $\tau$ which has certain properties, and that's it's easy to determine if a set is in it or not *and* to find subsets of it that contain a given element. A common example of such a subset is a so called "base" of a topology, which has the properties of covering the space and "almost" being closed under intersection, an example of a base is for the topology of $\mathbb R^n$ (or any metric space for that matter), where we take the set of open balls as a base.

Answer (score 1):

You've already defined a topology $\tau$ on $X=\{0,1,2\}$, namely $\{\emptyset, \{0\}, X\}$ which indeed fulfills the axioms.

And for each $S \in \tau$ and each $x \in S$ we can just take $U_x=S$ and are done with it. $\{2\}$ is not open and indeed for $2 \in \{2\}$ we cannot find a member of $\tau$ that contains $2$ (the only candidate is $X$ itself) *and* is a subset of $\{2\}$, obviously.

The left to right implication of your proposition is just a triviality and the right to left one only needs that a topology $\tau$ is closed under unions. The proposition is setting up the idea for a so-called base for $\tau$, I think.

Comment: Your second paragraph gets the idea I wanted to express. I wanted to take a bigger hypothetic topology and verify if it is in fact a topology thanks to the $\Longleftarrow$ implication but it has to take open sets $U_x$ so we must already know if the taken subsets form a topology or not. I am now confused about the proposition that feels like not having sense or useful properties...

Comment: @John In a base for $\tau$ we pick the $U_x$ from a (hopefully) smaller subfamily of $\tau$ we call a *base* for $\tau$ and then the right to left implication is a useful way to check openness once the base is chosen; the left to right implication is then the definition for a base, really. It's what the last paragraph hints at.